# Unable to connect to R-studio installed in HDInsight cluster

Tags: rstudio-server

I have installed an HDInsight cluster and have allowed all the ports to internet access. But still I am unable to access the RStudio-server from the internet. Would you please be able to help me let know what am I missing. I have created the Network Security groups and the Virtual Network as well.

Thanks